# Non-admin deployment to IIS gets ERROR_DACFX_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER (admin works fine)

Tags: sql-server-2012, webdeploy, visual-studio-2015, iis-8.5

I'm having a deployment issue that only surfaces when I switch to non-admin domain user accounts. When I deploy with an Active Directory domain admin account, everything deploys. But when I change to a domain user account, I get the following error:

*ERROR_DACFX_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER
Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedFatalException: The SQL provider cannot run with dacpac option because of a missing dependency. Please make sure that DacFx is installed.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DACFX_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER.*

As suggested in the error link, I used Web Platform Installer to install all three of the suggested items on the IIS server:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Data-Tier Application Framework
- SQL Server 2012 Transact-SQL ScriptDom
- SQL Server System CLR Types 11.0

But no dice; I still get the same error.

I have a dev / test environment as follows:

- Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2015 Community
- All servers and VMs run
  Server 2012 R2
- VM running IIS 8.0
- VM running SQL Server 2012

Other Info:

- Under IIS, I have set the site with its own App Pool which points to its own directory created under c:/inetpub/. The directory permissions have been set up as suggested (i.e. Local Service and even the domain user account attempting to deploy have read, write, modify, execute permissions).
- I have followed the instructions here (https: //blogs. technet. microsoft. com/leesab/2014/07/30/delegating-iis-administration-to-domain-users-non-administrators/) on delegating domain users to deploy. (Had to break up the link since I need at least 10 reps to be able to post more than 2 links)
- I have followed the instructions here (https://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/configure-the-web-deployment-handler) on authorizing domain users for deployment.

Online searches have yielded nada. Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.

P.S. This is my first post to Stack Overflow so any suggestions for improvement are appreciated.

Comment: Was there an option to install the Data Tier tools for all users?  Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Yes, I've tried restarting the site, restarting IIS, and also rebooting... no luck. I don't recall if there was an option to install Data Tier tools for all users. Please let me know how I can check this now and will try immediately.

Comment: Found a solution to this?

Comment: No, still looking. Am thinking at the end of this dev cycle, just re-installing everything and starting from scratch.